# Assertion Failure in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, flickr

I am taking the iTunes U Stanford iOS Class and am working on one of the assignments to build a little Flickr app. I am getting an error that I cannot seem to be able to debug which comes up as

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2280.1/UITableView.m:5336 2012-08-03
>   10:59:24.596 Assignment 4[4611:c07] (null) libc++abi.dylib: terminate
>   called throwing an exception

My code for the tableviewcontroller in question:

```
#import "PlacesPhotosTableViewController.h"

@interface PlacesPhotosTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *placeToDisplay;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *photosInPlace;
@end

@implementation PlacesPhotosTableViewController
@synthesize placeToDisplay = _placeToDisplay;
@synthesize photosInPlace = _photosInPlace;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithPlace:(NSDictionary *)place
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.placeToDisplay = place;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)photosInPlace
{
    if (_photosInPlace == nil)
    {
        _photosInPlace = [FlickrFetcher photosInPlace:self.placeToDisplay maxResults:50];
    }

    return _photosInPlace;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog([self.placeToDisplay valueForKeyPath:@"description._content"]);

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.photosInPlace count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photos";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSString *string = [[self.photosInPlace objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"description._content"];

    cell.textLabel.text = string;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: See also register your cell identifier.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813498/custom-table-cell-reuse-dequeue

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`CellIdentifier` I bet your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning `nil`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photos";

    /** NOTE: This method can return nil so you need to account for that in code */
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // NOTE: Add some code like this to create a new cell if there are none to reuse
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    NSString *string = [[self.photosInPlace objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     valueForKeyPath:@"description._content"];

    cell.textLabel.text = string;

    return cell;
}
```

That's probably why `[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]` is failing... because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is returning a null value and then `configureCellForDisplay` is expecting a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: That worked! Out of curiosity, why would a cell ever be null?

Comment: A simple example would be when it tries to render the very first cell.  No UITableViewCells have been created so there are none to reuse.

Comment: odd considering I didn't have to do it for the other table I have

Comment: A cell is nil if there is no reusable cell with that identifier. Happens if you didn't define such a cell in the interface builder and didn't create one from code (yet).

Answer (score 2):

This line here

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photos";
```

Does this match the cell identifier in your storyboard? I found these not matching was the cause of the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and solve it  cause i forgot to add

```
return cell;
```

now its resolved.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(tableView==notiTblView){

        NSLog(@"TABLE NEW");

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        UIImageView *imageview;
        UILabel *label;
        UILabel *lblDetail;

        if(cell == nil)
        {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            imageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 3,30, 37)];
            label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 100, 20)];
            lblDetail=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 35, 100, 30)];
            lblDetail.numberOfLines=3;

            imageview.tag=100;
            label.tag=101;
            lblDetail.tag=102;

            label.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            label.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

            lblDetail.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            lblDetail.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
            lblDetail.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];


            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDetail];

        }

        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        UIImageView *img=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        UILabel *lbl=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];

        NSString * stirngId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"photoID"]];

        if ([dicImages_msg valueForKey:[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productName"]]) {

            img.image=[dicImages_msg valueForKey:[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productName"]];

        }
        else
        {
            if (!isDragging_msg && !isDecliring_msg)
            {
                [dicImages_msg setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"] forKey:[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productName"]];
                [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(download_Noti_image:) withObject:indexPath];
            }
            else
            {
                img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"];
            }
        }

        lbl.text=[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"memberName"];
        lbl.text=[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"memberName"];

        return cell;

       /* static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
        cell.textLabel.text=[[notificationARRAY objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"memberName"];
        return cell;*/

   }else{
       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
       TblCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       if (cell==nil) {
           cell = [[TblCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }

       NSLog(@"arr..in table..%@",PostedItem);
       cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

       if([[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productType"] isEqualToString :@"Video"]){
           cell.postedimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_icon.png"];
       }else{

           if ([dicImages_msg valueForKey:[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productName"]]) {

               cell.postedimage.image=[dicImages_msg valueForKey:[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productName"]];

           }else
            {
                if (!isDragging_msg && !isDecliring_msg)
                    {
                        [dicImages_msg setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"] forKey:[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"productName"]];
                        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:) withObject:indexPath];
                    } else
                        {
                            cell.postedimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"];
                        }
            }

       }
//*******************User image
    if ([dic_usrImg valueForKey:[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbUrl"]]) {

        cell.profileImage.image=[dic_usrImg valueForKey:[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbUrl"]];

    }
    else
    {
        if (!isDragging_msg && !isDecliring_msg)
        {
            [dic_usrImg setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"] forKey:[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"thumbUrl"]];
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_IMAGE4:) withObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.profileImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"];
        }
    }
//********************************
    [cell.btnImage setTag:100000+indexPath.row];
    [cell.btnImage  addTarget:self action:@selector(Shopw_feedImg:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//***************
    cell.postedimage.tag=indexPath.row;
    [cell.postedimage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onImageClick:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tap setDelegate:self];
    [cell.postedimage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.membername.text=[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    [cell.membername sizeToFit];
    //[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"memberID"];  
    cell.productName.text= [[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"photoTitle"];
    //@"hello this is a test doviumbmvbhdf asx";
   // with new sffhy dgftn tun dgh ";
  //  NSLog(@"Str Length...%d",[cell.productName.text length]);
    if ([cell.productName.text length]>38) {

        NSLog(@"greater then...%@",cell.productName.text);
         cell.productName.numberOfLines=2;
        CGRect frame=cell.postedimage.frame;
        frame.origin.y=130;
        cell.postedimage.frame=frame;
        CGRect Prdctframe=cell.productName.frame;
        frame.size.height=40.0f;
        cell.productName.frame=Prdctframe;
        //cell.postedimage.frame.origin.y=115.0f;
    }//[[PostedItem objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"photoTitle"];
      //@"szfgfgbjmghufho stdogb ryt;o esftesi rdetg ry ry ry ";//
    else
    {
        cell.productName.numberOfLines=1;
        CGRect frame=cell.postedimage.frame;
        frame.origin.y=110;
        cell.postedimage.frame=frame;
        CGRect Prdctframe=cell.productName.frame;
        Prdctframe.size.height=20.0f;
        cell.productName.frame=Prdctframe;
          NSLog(@"less then...");
    }

    //[cell.productName sizeToFit];
 //   cell.profileImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"timthumb.jpg"];
    return cell;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not Creating Cell in method

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

You only reusing the cell from this method which returns `nil` initially.

You have to create cell by this below given code in your method.

```
if(cell==nil){

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
```