# Custom Table Cell Reuse / Dequeue

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I know similar issues have been posted before but I can't find a solution for me within them so please bear with me...

I have a tableview with a custom table cell in xcode. The cell is currently nothing more than a label:

```
SiteFileCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.fileNameLabel.text = [self.listDir.filesInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

This works great. I am essentially doing a directory drill down structure. When I select a cell it goes to the next level by pushing a new tableview to the navigation controller stack and reloading all the table cells.

At this point I see an often reported error:

*unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard*

So following research I see the suggestion that I should be registering the type:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[SiteFileCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FileCell"];
```

If I do that, the thing works well but none of the cells display any label at all!

I've seen some reference to maybe requiring custom code in the initWithStyle method of the cell's class, but I can't quite work out what would be required there, so can someone give me a bit more of a pointer please?

Comment: Can you post the whole of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method please.

Comment: you should instantiate your cell, just like if ( cell == nil ) {cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}

Comment: Also, when you are going to the level, are you using the same tableView ?

Comment: If you create your custom cell in Interface Builder, you can set the identifier there and it will just work.

Comment: The answer to this depends on where you created you custom cell, so where did you create it, xib, storyboard, or code?

Comment: @deathhorse No, you don't have to do this any more when you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: and either make the cell in the storyboard, or register the nib or class.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I created the cell as a prototype cell in the storyboard originally, and yes I am using the same tableview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of registering a *class* register a *nib*. That nib is the nib where you have designed your table view cell subclass. It contains just one top-level object, the cell, and that cell has been designated a SiteFileCell. Presto, it will all just work.

See the complete explanation (with downloadable code) in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells

See esp. the subsection "Designing a cell in a nib".

Comment: This definitely works - still not sure why I have no issue using designed cells in the storyboard intially but when I programatically push a new tableview controller I have to change to use a nib... but it works at least, so thanks!

Comment: Because you are not getting the "new tableview controller" from a storyboard. You can design a cell in a storyboard using the storyboard "prototype" feature, but only if your UITableViewController comes from a storyboard. You could have done that - make a storyboard, design your UITableViewController in it, give it an identifier, and fetch it out with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`. But as soon as you decided to instantiate your UITableViewController some *other* way, you gave up that feature.

Comment: Again, please read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells It explains all the possible ways you can obtain a custom cell.

Comment: Yeah @matt, I've read it but I still don't understand why in one instance it works with a custom cell and in the other I *need* to use a NIB - the implication is that either should be fine...

Comment: "Instance" is the operative word. It all depends on where this cell instance is to come from. You are giving the table view instructions in this regard. If the cell instance is to come from a nib, you register for that nib. If it is sufficient to instantiate the class directly, you register the class. In your case, you have used the nib to draw the outlet connection for `fileNameLabel`, so if you want that outlet property to work, you must load the nib. Otherwise `fileNameLabel` is nil.

Comment: It sounds from your question is that your confusion *might* be that you don't understand how nibs and outlets work. This part of my book might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

Comment: Nono, sorry, I'm not explaining myself well - to be clear your advice has worked well, thank you, your book is very helpful, what I mean is I don't get why within the same project I've done this once using the storyboard with no issue, but the second time I've been _forced_ to use a nib - is it something to do with the fact that I'm pushing the same controller onto the stack again as that's the only change I can see.

Comment: If the cell is to be instantiated from the storyboard, you don't need to register anything. If the cell is to be instantiated from a nib, you need to register the nib.

Comment: matt - sorry, in regards to your secondmost commenent - I completely missed this and am now understanding - apologies!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a XIB for cell you can set the identifier in the XIB file only.